Solana Wallet in React Native
TLDR;
Is there a SDK or a guide to connect a Solana wallet to any dapp, through React Native?
Details:
So we are developing a wallet app using React Native and we want to connect the wallet to the dapp, opened in react-native-webview. We are aware of the wallet-standard repository in which we believe we need to follow it to allow the wallet connection.
We have tried to follow its guide, up until step no.8, but we are stuck on no.9 where it mentions it needs to be run in extension or webview.
We were thinking to somehow browserify the built lib and inject those to react-native-webview, but we are wondering if there's easier-to-maintain way of doing this
